# ¿Cómo devolver/renderizar varios diccionarios en Django/Python?

Tags: python, django

Tengo estos dos (o más) diccionarios:

```
def Index(request):
nav={
    "nav":{
        "Servicio": "servicio", 
        "Detalles": "servicio", 
        "Precios": "productos", 
        "Contacto": "asesoramiento"
    }
}

content={
    "content":{
        "contenido 1": "descripción 1", 
        "contenido 2": "descripción 2", 
        "contenido 3": "descripción 3", 
        "contenido 4": "descripción 4"
    }
}
content.update(nav)
return render(request, "index.html", nav)
```

Lo que quiero saber es cómo renderizarlo en Django/Python, ya que para renderizar un solo diccionario estaba utilizando:

```
return render(request, "index.html", nav)
```

Pero con dos diccionarios no tengo idea cómo es, intente de varias formas pero sin éxito.

Como verán, debe ser un problema de lo mas simple pero recién estoy aprendiendo Django/Python y algunas cosas se me complican. Desde ya muchas gracias!

---

**Actualización**:
Utilizando content.update(nav) o nav.update(content) el codigo compila correctamente y puedo hacer un for del nav, sin embargo, no recibo datos de content. El código en html lo tengo así:

```
{% for title, desc in content.items %}
<div class="col2">
    <div>
        <h2>{{title}}</h2>
    </div>
    <p>{{desc}}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Tengo exactamente la misma estructura de llamada de datos en el nav y funciona correctamente.

Comment: Añade a tu pregunta el codigo de como hiciste los updates o el contexto en si.

Comment: Ahí actualice y puse la función entera

Comment: Lo solucione!, añadí tanto content.update(nav) como nav.update(content) y funciona, no se si es la forma mas optima pero funciona, por otra parte, no se cómo funcionaría si tengo varios diccionarios

Comment: Ok, si fue de ayuda mi pregunta recuerda aceptarla!

Comment: fue de ayuda pero aun no soluciono el problema principal que es renderizar varios diccionarios, aunque si no hay mas respuestas la voy a considerar. Gracias nuevamente.

Comment: Ok, no hay problema, pero como dije antes, renderisar varios diccionarios por separado es practicamente imposible.

Comment: como sería eso de crear un diccionario padre para actualizar todos los diccionarios? eso me serviria. Gracias

Comment: Por ejemplo crear un diccionario llamado "context", y hacerle los updates a dicho diccionario, es mas coherente ese nombre del diccionario que el nombre "nav" o "content".

Comment: Es mi opinion y mi comodidad en cuanto a programar, aunque la manera anterior es totalmente valida.

Comment: cómo hago para cargar dos diccionarios en una variable? estoy tratando por ejemplo: "updates={nav, content}", "nav.update({nav, content})" pero no hay caso. Pd: por los nombres no te preocupes porque igualmente puse nombres de ejemplo para que sea mas facil etnender la situación.

Comment: no se puede poner los 2 dicts en un dict, como lo estas haciendo, ya lo intente. En dado caso que no obtengas esos diccionarios por datos externos pon manualmente los diccionarios en uno solo, con la misma estructura de un update a un dict.

Comment: Me sirvió de esa forma, muchas gracias!

Comment: Ok encantado de ayudarte!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacer un update a cualquiera de los dos diccionarios, de la siguiente manera:

```
content.update(nav)
```

De esta manera unira los 2 diccionarios y podras renderisarlo sin problema y su estructura se vera algo asi:

```
{

'content': {
    'contenido 1': 'descripción 1', 
    'contenido 2': 'descripción 2', 
    'contenido 3': 'descripción 3', 
    'contenido 4': 'descripción 4'

}, 

'nav': {
    'Servicio': 'servicio', 
    'Detalles': 'servicio', 
    'Precios': 'productos', 
    'Contacto': 'asesoramiento'
}
```

}

Tambien puedes crear un diccionario "padre" por asi decirlo y a dicho diccionario hacerle el update de los 2 diccionarios.

Si quieres hacerlo por separado me temo que es imposible, pero bien puede haber alguna manera de hacerlo de la cual desconosco totalmente, pero dudo que la haya.

---

**Actualizasion:**

De acuerdo al problema que planteas, deberia funcionar, deberia iterar sin ningun problema, de hecho lo estoy probando y funciona.

Si quieres iterar al `nav` o al `content`, recuerda que debe ser por separado.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por su respuesta, actualice el post para comentar la situación actual.

Answer (score 0):

Si tienes dos listas separadas así:

```
nav={
        "Servicio": "servicio", 
        "Detalles": "servicio", 
        "Precios": "productos", 
        "Contacto": "asesoramiento"
        },
content={
        "contenido 1": "descripción 1", 
        "contenido 2": "descripción 2", 
        "contenido 3": "descripción 3", 
        "contenido 4": "descripción 4"
        }
nav.update(content)
```

**Actualización:**
Creo que a "devolver" varios diccionarios te refieres a unir?
en ese caso deberias usar `nav.update(content)`

Comment: Eso esta mal, hacerlo daria error, el contexto debe ser un diccionario no una lista.

Comment: Corrige tu pregunta porfavor.

Comment: ok corregida mi respuesta, gracias no leí correctamente pense solo en unir

Comment: Ok, no hay problema.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por su respuesta, actualice el post para comentar la situación actual.

Answer (score 0):

También puedes unirlos de la siguiente forma (**kwargs):

```
nuevo_dict = {**content, **nav}
```